# Ruby on Rails form_for creates empty object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have a partial named _form.html.erb in my alerts/views/ folder. I render that partial from the show page in my agencies/views/ folder.

Everything renders properly, and the partial does create a new alert, but the alert is completely empty.

**alerts_controller create method**

```
def create
  @alert = Alert.new(body: params[:body],
                   severity: params[:severity],
                   agency_id: @current_member.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @alert.save
        format.html { redirect_to @alert.agency, notice: 'Alert was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @alert}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @alert.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(Alert.new) do |f| %>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :severity %><br>
      <%= f.number_field :severity %>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

There are no errors, except that the alert created is completely empty. The body, severity, and agency_id variables are all nil.

I have tried replacing the line

```
<%= form_for(Alert.new) do |f| %>
```

with this:

```
<%= form_for(@alert) do |f| %>
```

and adding this line:

```
@alert = Alert.new
```

to the show method in the agency controller.

But the same thing happens either way. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is the log starting when I hit submit, and ending before loading the redirect in the alerts.create method.

```
Started POST "/alerts" for ::1 at 2016-03-31 18:29:43 -0400
Processing by AlertsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CgpepnYUec9uUoE/Ys6SAkOlzmK+w2q9IN782sXNoXnB3UyuegiS6m+W+mW+nXu4EIL8P8xH6JdigU8FfmzhVw==", "alert"=>{"body"=>"This is the body text", "severity"=>"12345"}, "commit"=>"Create Alert"}
  Account Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  Agency Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "agencies".* FROM "agencies" WHERE "agencies"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "alerts" ("agency_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["agency_id", 2], ["created_at", "2016-03-31 22:29:43.014846"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-31 22:29:43.014846"]]
   (135.8ms)  commit transaction
  Agency Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "agencies".* FROM "agencies" WHERE "agencies"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/agencies/2
Completed 302 Found in 141ms (ActiveRecord: 136.2ms)
```

When I comment out the alerts.create method and add this line:

```
render plain: params
```

This is the output:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"3OfteFX41SV/5NxpTcKbP7AKhLm/ZKah+NXVn84e2xwXMP9wWeQ+AH4gpzORkXKF4y225M3gJIu6imZAdb+bMg==", 
"alert"=>{"body"=>"This is the body text.", "severity"=>"12345"},
"commit"=>"Create Alert", "controller"=>"alerts", "action"=>"create"}
```

Comment: Could you share `console` log ? Try this one:  `@alert = Alert.new({body: params[:body],
                   severity: params[:severity],
                   agency_id: @current_member.id})`

Comment: also u can try comment everything in create method and add this one then trigger it. `render plain params` look at data how u passing it.

Comment: Could you explain your second comment more? Cheers

Comment: `def create render plain: params end`  You can see your sending params to create method.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the output from `render plain: params`

Comment: Why do i see `accounts` and `agencies` in post method ? where ist coming from ?

Comment: The params coming in pretty much explain it, no? You're accessing `params[:body]` but the body is under `params[:alert][:body]`. It's unclear why you're creating an alert from the agency controller, though. Also, using something like `pry` would allow you to directly inspect the parameters in the controller.

Comment: I'm not sure where it is coming from, but an agency is a type of account. It belongs to account as a member. I have no clue where those are coming from though.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Check post below, that should work !

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks so much that worked! But now I'm confused because we have another form which is for Posts, and directly accesses params[:body], params[:title], etc. Why does my code pass in an alert with that information, instead of that information in params?

Comment: @7urkm3n Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MatthewCliatt, Enjoy np))

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Probably because you're using the correct controller.

Comment: So should I use the agency controller to accept this post request and create an alert there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is evident from your `params` debugging. The `params` hash has an `alert` key in it. The `alert` value is a hash of `body` and `severity`.

In your controller, you reference `params[:body]` and `params[:severity]`. Those should be `params[:alert][:body]` and `params[:alert][:severity]`.

Was there a reason not to use Rails' strong parameters? You could refactor to something like:

```
def create
  @alert = Alert.new(alert_params.merge(agency_id: @current_member.id)
  …
end
…

private

  def alert_params
    params.require(:alert).permit(:body, :severity)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked! But now I'm confused because we have another form which is for Posts, and directly accesses params[:body], params[:title], etc. Why does my code pass in an alert with that information, instead of that information in params?

Comment: Also, someone once said that using form_for(Alert.new) isn't as good as using form_for(@alert). What's the difference? Should I sway one way?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt If you're not *editing* anything with that form it's fine, if a little weird.

Comment: There's no difference in the use-case you present. Where use an `@alert` instance variable can help is when you are sharing your form HTML in a partial between the `new` and `edit` actions. The `new` action will set `@alert` to `Alert.new`, and the `edit` action will set it to something like `Alert.find(params[:id])`. The same form HTML can work in either case.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Between `@alert = Alert.new` and `Alert.new` nothing difference. For you if u r using `_form.html.erb` then `@alert` would be better and right choice. Because you can use one `_form.html.erb` for `new` and `edit` methods.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I would guess that the Posts form is not using `form_for` on a Post object. It's probably just using `form_tag` and trying to manage the params itself. Your code using the model object and `form_for` is more idiomatic Rails.

Comment: Got it. So for my use-case, should I move the logic for accepting the post request and handling the creation of the alert to a new method in the agency controller? So that I could easily do @agency.alerts.create()? Is that more idiomatic?

Comment: To be honest, I typically just do it the way you've done it here. In my view, your AgenciesController should be focussed on listing, showing, creating Agency models. Yes, it feels a bit 'off' to have the AlertsController redirecting to Agencies→show after successfully creating a new alert, but I've found that to be the least-worst option in the real world. Most clients want pages that include UI to manipulate more than one model. Unless you want to go single-page-application and use Rails as nothing more than a JSON API endpoint, I've not found a better way than this.

Comment: Yes. (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one-association-force-reload-false)

Answer (score 1):

In the `create method` params supposed to be like this.

Because your params `"alert"=>{"body"=>"This is the body text.", "severity"=>"12345"}`

```
def create
  @alert = Alert.new(body: params[:alert][:body],
                   severity: params[:alert][:severity],
                   agency_id: @current_member.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @alert.save
        format.html { redirect_to @alert.agency, notice: 'Alert was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @alert}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @alert.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```